# Why murmur is slower than built-in MD5/SHA1 method

Tags: c#, hash

I just tried the murmur hash C# port...

However I am very disappointed about its performance. It appears to be slower than the built-in C# MD5/SHA1 computeHash method.

Debug mode is fine, and murmur is faster in this mode. If you switch to Release mode, it's  slower than SHA1 or MD5 hash method.

Comment: Which implementation? For example, try this one - http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/08/murmurhash3-ultra-fast-hash-algorithm.html

Comment: Did you profile ? What was the results ?

Comment: if performance is an issue, you might better off to implement in unmanaged C++ and either P/Invoke to it, or use IJW from C++/CLI

Comment: I upload my testing code to https://github.com/arisoyang/Murmur3Hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason, it should set to x64 or anycpu instead of x86

here are the testing result.

```
Release - Target AnyCPU


Murmur Hash profile...
 test Bytes     :2621440000
 iterations     :10000
 totalSeconds   :**1.787**
 bytesPerSecond :1466950195.85898
 mbitsPerSecond :1398.99272523783





BuildinSHA Hash profile...
 test Bytes     :2621440000
 iterations     :10000
 totalSeconds   :**5.956**
 bytesPerSecond :440134318.334453
 mbitsPerSecond :419.74479516454

Release - Target X86

Murmur Hash profile...
 test Bytes     :2621440000
 iterations     :10000
 totalSeconds   :10.612
 bytesPerSecond :247026008.292499
 mbitsPerSecond :235.582359592914


BuildinSHA Hash profile...
 test Bytes     :2621440000
 iterations     :10000
 totalSeconds   :5.987
 bytesPerSecond :437855353.265408
 mbitsPerSecond :417.571404710205

Release - Target X64



Murmur Hash profile...
 test Bytes     :2621440000
 iterations     :10000
 totalSeconds   :1.732
 bytesPerSecond :1513533487.29792
 mbitsPerSecond :1443.41801385681


BuildinSHA Hash profile...
 test Bytes     :2621440000
 iterations     :10000
 totalSeconds   :5.968
 bytesPerSecond :439249329.758713
 mbitsPerSecond :418.900804289544
```

Soure code :

https://github.com/arisoyang/Murmur3Hash